# appium : webview : selenium : How to automate touchend event on a div?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, automation, appium

I want to automate a hybrid app using appium. 
My app uses touchend events instead of click events for div
How do I automate this touchend events in appium?

For simple click I can find an element and then perform click by simply doing `WebElement.click();`

How to fire an event for touchend?

Answer (score 2):

I have spend the last few days looking into this same issue.  Eventually what I have found is that the Appium touch actions only work on the *NATIVE* context.  However when you are testing/automating a web application you are in *WEBVIEW* context.  So you have to switch to NATIVE, perform the touch actions, then switch back.

Ok, so that doesn't sound to bad.  But they can't let it be that simple.  So you can not use your Selenium WebElement as an argument in the Touch Actions.  You will either have to re-find it using the NATIVE context, or use the elements location and dimensions to calculate a touch position and use that.  However, the X and Y coordinates in the NATIVE context are different than those in the WEBVIEW context.  So if you need them to be exact, then you have to translate them.

Well, at least that is where I am now.  Perhaps someone else can provide some more or better details.

Here is some sample code for a *tap* which ignores the pixel translation issue.  I have only tested this with iOS, but it should work with Android as well.

```
private void tapElement(AppiumDriver appiumDriver, WebElement element) {
   // Locate center of element
   Point location = element.getLocation();
   Dimension size = element.getSize();
   int tapX = location.getX() + (size.getWidth() / 2);
   int tapY = location.getY() + (size.getHeight() / 2);

   // Execute tap
   String originalContext = appiumDriver.getContext();
   appiumDriver.context("NATIVE_APP");
   TouchAction action = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
   action.tap(tapX, tapY).perform();
   appiumDriver.context(originalContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through documentation?

https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions.md

Comment: I tried touchActions. But it is giving me following error when i perform an action on webElement : `org.openqa.selenium.webdriverexception not yet implemented` however It works for a sample native app element. I am using the latest version of appium 1.3.7 , java-client-2.2.0 , selenium-java-2.45.0 , selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2 ,ios 8.2 simulator